# How to use extended models for ApplicationUser in Asp.Net core 2.1, from manage profile page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a Customer class and Employee class, they extend from ApplicationUser, that shares common properties. I don't know how to implement Customer and Employee from the Identity/Pages/Account/Manage/Index. Since I'm only using one Model(InputModel). I got if statements displaying customer forms or employee forms on the view, but when a Customer updates their data, the employee validation is triggered and vice-versa because my properties are all in InputModel.

Model

```
     public class InputModel
        {
        public string CustomerUserId { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeId { get; set; }

         //ApplicationUser
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        //CustomerUser
        [Required]
        public string InvoiceMethod { get; set; }

        //Employee
        [Required]
        public string SsnTaxId { get; set; }
        }
```

Code

```
  if (user.Employee != null && user.Employee.EmployeeId != null)
        {
            Input = new InputModel
            {
                EmployeeId = user.Employee.EmployeeId,
                Email = email,
             };
         }
          else if (user.Employee != null && user.Employee.EmployeeId != null)
        {
            Input = new InputModel
            {
                EmployeeId = user.Employee.EmployeeId,
                SSnTaxId= user.Employee.SsnTaxId,
             };
         }
          else if (user.Customer!= null && user.Customer.CustomerUserId!= null)
        {
            Input = new InputModel
            {
                CustomerUserId = user.Customer.CustomerUserId,
                InvoiceMethod= user.Customer.InvoiceMethod,
             };
         }
```

View

```
          //ApplictionUser properties
      @if (Model.Input != null && Model.Input.CustomerUserId != null)
        {
           <input asp-for="Input.InvoiceMethod" class="form-control" type="text" />
           // display Customer Properties
         }
      @if (Model.Input != null && Model.Input.EmployeeId != null)
        {
          <input asp-for="Input.SsnTaxId" class="form-control" type="text" />
          //display employee properties
        }
```

Comment: So what is the exact question? what have you tried so far? posting the whole code does not really help, please post the most important part and what you have tried so far and what did not work

Comment: I want a user to be able to update their info. It works, but for example if a employee update data then the I get validation errors because the customer properties are required, eventhough not customer properties ate displayed.

Comment: I tried to inherit from InputModel by using CustomerInputModel : InputModel but I could get the form to display anything.